# c++ inheritance problem and pointers. Trying to access child class with a pointer but the function is not being able to be found

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance

So I am coding in c++ and am having a problem with inheritance and pointers. I am trying to access how many notches are in the gun slinger object (gun) but it is saying person has no such function. gun is a child class of person so I am a bit confused. here is the code

side note the error is p->getnotches() in main and it says (class "Person" has no member "getnotches")

```
          
    

        int main()
    {
    
         Person *p;
         Gunslinger gun("Doc Holiday", 5);
         //PokerPlayer poker("Billy Jack");
         //BadDude bad("Billy Kid", 4);
    
         Person p1("James Cagney");
         cout << "Persons name is: " << p1.getName() << endl;
         Person p2 = p1;
         Person p3, p4;
    
         p4 = p3 = p1;
    
         p = new Person("Jack Benny");
    
         cout << "Person name is: " << p->getName() << endl;
         cout << "Person 1 name is: " << p1.getName() << endl;
         cout << "Person 2 name is: " << p2.getName() << endl;
         cout << "Person 3 name is: " << p3.getName() << endl;
         cout << "Person 4 name is: " << p4.getName() << endl;
    
         delete p;
         p = &gun;
                                                                                         
         cout << "Gunslinger name: " << p->getName() << " and number of notched on gun is: " <<  
         p->getnotches() << endl;
         return 0;

  }
```

```
#ifndef PERSON_H
#define PERSON_H
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Person
{
private:
    char *name;

public:
    Person();
    Person(string name);
    virtual string getName();
    virtual ~Person();
};
#endif
```

```
    // no default constructor
Person::Person()
{
}

// this function assigns a name to person object
Person::Person(string n)
{
    name = new char[n.length() + 1];

    strcpy(name, n.c_str());
}

// this functions grabs the name of the person object
string Person::getName()
{
    return name;
}

Person::~Person()
{
    delete[] name;
}
```

```
    #ifndef GUNSLINGER_H
#define GUNSLINGER_H
#pragma once
#include "Person.hpp"
#include <cstring>
#include <string>

class Gunslinger : public Person
{
private:
    char *name;
    int notches;
    double drawTime;

public:
    Gunslinger(string n, int cylinders);
    int getnotches();
    virtual string getName();
    ~Gunslinger();
};
#endif
```

```
    #include "Gunslinger.hpp"

Gunslinger::Gunslinger(string n, int clinders)
{
    name = new char[n.length() + 1];
    strcpy(name, n.c_str());
    notches = clinders;
}

string Gunslinger::getName()
{
    return name;
}

int Gunslinger::getnotches()
{
    return notches;
}

Gunslinger::~Gunslinger()
{
    delete[] name;
}
```

Comment: Compiler doesn't look down the class hierarchy to look for functions that may be defined in the other classes. On a pointer of type `Person*` you can only call functions from `Person` class and nothing else.

Comment: Note, you are at risk of mixing std::string and cstring. You should remove the cstring include

Answer (score 0):

In this expression

```
p->getnotches()
```

the static type of the pointer `p` is `Person *` due to this declaration

```
Person *p;
```

So the compiler searches in the class `Person` the function `getnotches` and does not find it because the class does not have such a function.

```
class Person
{
private:
    char *name;

public:
    Person();
    Person(string name);
    virtual string getName();
    virtual ~Person();
};
```

You need to use `dynamic_cast` (if the compiler supports it) or `reinterpret_cast` with the pointer.

Comment: in order to fix this would I have to cast the pointer to a gunslinger? or what are some other solutions

Comment: @Kninja99 Yes you need for example to use dynamic_cast. or reinterpret_cast

Comment: One should never use `reinterpret_cast` when casting to related classes in a hierarchy. You have to use `static_cast` or `dynamic_cast`.

Answer (score 0):

Although you have a Gunslinger object, you're treating it as a Person object and the Person class does not have a getnotches method. I'm not sure why you want to have a Person* to a Gunslinger object. Just use the Gunslinger 'gun' instead of the Person* 'p'.

cout << "Gunslinger name: " << gun.getName() << " and number of notched on gun is: " <<
gun.getnotches() << endl;